# Stopping a for loop in a while loop

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a for loop in a while loop running on a condition. The button changes the condition variable but the for loop does not stop.

```
self.cancel_button = tk.Button(self, text="cancel", command=self.cancel)
self.cancel_button.grid(row=0)

def cancel(self):
    self.break_main = 1

self.break_main = 0
while self.break_main == 0:
    for x in list:
        #do stuff
```

Comment: Try: `while True; if self.break_main: break` in your code

Comment: We can't work this out without you showing a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. All you have hear are loose fragments. We don't know how you start your thread, if you are using the same object in both of those methods or any number of things. I cooked up an example similar to you code that works. I'll post as an answer but really its a guess.

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
self.cancel_button = tk.Button(self, text="cancel", command=self.cancel)
self.cancel_button.grid(row=0)

def cancel(self):
    self.break_main = 1

self.break_main = 0
while True:
    if self.break_main:
        break
    #do stuff
```

Comment: This didn't stop the loop. I added a print in the function to test if the function was working and it worked. It could be something else interfering with it maybe.

Comment: Shouldn't `command=cancel` instead of `command=self.cancel`? Maybe not.

Comment: All of this is in a class and the cancel function is outside the top part function. You use self. when referring to functions outside of the on you are calling from. There is no problem with the function executing, it is just the loop not stopping.

Comment: @RCampbell _You use self. when referring to functions outside of the on you are calling from_ ... um, not sure what that means but you use `self.` to call other methods on the same object.

Comment: Kinda what I meant to say. Call a method on the same object from another method on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it like this? I cant test it as tkinter is always hit and miss with my computer, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt.

```
def cancel(self):
    self.break_main = 1

while True:
    self.cancel_button = tk.Button(self, text="cancel", command=self.cancel)
    self.cancel_button.grid(row=0)
    if self.break_main:
       break
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that there is a for loop in the while loop causing it to wait for the for loop to finish.

Comment: what exactly is the for loop doing?

Answer (score 0):

This is like staring at the entrails of a goat to glean some meaning... but here is an example that does what you want. You have not posted the other 90% of the code so its hard to guess where you went wrong. I posted this partially just to show that working examples can be written and they make the job of answering questions easier.

```
try:
    import tkinter
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tkinter # python 2

import threading
import time

class Foo(tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        cancel_button = tkinter.Button(self, text="Stop While", command=self.cancel)
        cancel_button.place(x=50, y=50)
        self.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
        self._thread = threading.Thread(target=self.while_thread)
        self._thread.isDaemon()
        self._thread.start()

    def cancel(self):
        self.break_main = 1

    def while_thread(self):
        print("Thread start")
        self.break_main = 0
        while self.break_main == 0:
            time.sleep(.1)
        print("Thread done")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Foo(root)
    root.mainloop()
    print("Main Done")
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, the code is a couple hundred more lines and i wanted to keep the question simple. I have discovered the problem to be that there is a for loop running within the while loop which is delaying the stoppage of the while loop.

Comment: So my new question is: How to stop a for loop within a while loop from a button.

Comment: @R.Campbell there are a couple of options, depending on what your `for` loop is doing. But considering your example `while self.break_main == 0:` does polling, you could do something similar inside the loop: `if self.break_main == 0: break`.